# adding custom code to joomla

Tags: joomla

I fear the way I am doing this would be inappropriate for production servers. I dont know why it would be, but I suspect there is a more 'mom approved' way, which is what Im looking for.

On my test server, I have a joomla 2.5 setup. I have been learning by hacking the crap out of it. I created a folder [/custom] that holds some actually useful code (basically a small library that I can call upon from some modules), and my boss would like that code to be put on the production server. So : Is there a proper way to add custom code to Joomla? (code outside the scope of joomla, code that is unique to some website) I dont need to make it a plugin (I think), as some of it is literally 10 lines of code.

Ill bet theres a best practice or something but the docs are hiding it well.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding custom code to Joomla, however please be very careful when editing core file. I would strongly recommend not doing it. It can cause problems which many users have experienced in the past with functions and security. What sort of code do you want to add? for example extra php functions etc. If you explain a little more then I might be able to recommend the best place to insert it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are making a custom Joomla library. You can package this up in a zip as a library and install into Joomla. All you have to add into the zip is an xml file that tells Joomla how to handle the library. A good resource for that is here: http://www.ostraining.com/howtojoomla/how-tos/development/how-to-package-joomla-libraries

Once installed you can pull this library from any module or component that you add. Say you have a library named "jomadditions" with a file in that folder called "sample" you can add this code to Joomla and use it by doing the following:

```
jimport('jomadditions.sample');
function_in_sample();
// interact with sample's code just as if you had used require() on the file
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to build a Joomla component or a module. Take a look at the Joomla Compoenent Creator: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/ to get you started or learn here: http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction